# Applying CSS to sub theme created by Omega

Tags: theming

I am creating responsive theme. To create a theme I have created subtheme of [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme.

Until the creation of subtheme every thing was easy. Now after creating the subtheme I want to apply the CSS provided by the designer. But the problem is that designer has created different class name and div tags than [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega).

I am stuck now, I don't know from where should I start ?

What will be the best practice in such type of cases when subtheme and CSS provided by the designer has different class and divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to match up the original with the new if you can... Use something that can show you the class names like firebug, an add on for firefox (there is one for ie as well). It will take a while but that is usually what will pin point the classes if you can't get the original css. 
If you have the original css try to use it in your template directory. See which one was edited first, ( global.css, alpha... etc) then just drag the files to the new destination making sure your .info files are the same as well because it may be a relative region issue.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

1. rename in the CSS
2. rename in ALL .tpl.php file's theme

There are no other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

@ZioBudda is right. The easiest will be #1: Rename all your CSS classes.

I would suggest using something like the [Live CSS](http://drupal.org/project/live_css) module to make the task more manageable.